# Reverse Vowels of a String - 2 pointer solution not working

Tags: java, algorithm

This is leetcode problem I'm trying to solve with 2 pointer method. For some reason, my code is not accepted, and it times out. Can you advise what the issue is?

**Leetcode Problem:**
https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-vowels-of-a-string/submissions/

**My Solution:**

```
class Solution {
    public String reverseVowels(String s) {
        // O(1) to determine if something is vowel
        HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add('a');
        set.add('e');
        set.add('i');
        set.add('o');
        set.add('u');
        set.add('A');
        set.add('E');
        set.add('I');
        set.add('O');
        set.add('U');
        
        char[] character = s.toCharArray();

        int a_pointer = 0;
        int b_pointer = s.length() - 1;
        
        while (a_pointer < b_pointer) {
            if (set.contains(character[a_pointer]) && set.contains(character[b_pointer])) {
                char temp = character[a_pointer];
                character[a_pointer] = character[b_pointer];
                character[b_pointer] = temp;
            }
            
            if (!set.contains(character[a_pointer])) {
                a_pointer++;
            }
            if (!set.contains(character[b_pointer])) {
                b_pointer--;
            }
        }
        return new String(character);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if using two switch statements would be faster than using a `HashSet`?

Comment: What about _eg_ É?

Comment: Try using a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

You're not incrementing or decrementing your pointers in the condition where they are both vowels, so the loop keeps repeating. The code path enters the first condition, the vowels swap, and then restarts the loop, enters the first condition again, the vowels swap again, and so on.

Comment: Makes sense... I was thinking in terms of the "905. Sort array by parity" problem where there's 2 If statements that already account for even/odd numbers so the 2 pointers are automatically in/decremented.

Makes sense to add the in/decrement inside the first If case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to

- increment left index independently until it is on a vowel.
- then decrement the right index independently until it is on a vowel
- when left and right are both indexing vowels, then swap them
- increment left index, decrement right index.
- repeat the process until left index >= right index

One key point to remember is that this needs to work even if all the vowels are on one side of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with python, you can do something like this:

```
def reversevowels(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return s
    i, j = 0, len(s) - 1
    r = list(s)
    while i < j:
        if r[i].lower() not in 'aeiou':
            i += 1
        elif r[j].lower() not in 'aeiou':
            j -= 1
        else:
            r[i], r[j] = r[j], r[i]
            i += 1
            j -= 1
    return ''.join(r)
```